# How to make background colour always stick to 100% of a div, even when it's scrolled?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a `div` element with a `width: 100%` style. However, when I zoom up and horizontally scroll, the background disappears! Here's what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb03s.png.

Is there a way to make the background colour of the top bar `div` always **fill** the width of the screen? I am willing to use JavaScript but I'd rather not if there's a CSS solution that's fairly cross-browser.

**EDIT:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdmx2xqg/)

Comment: post a fiddle please

Comment: @scooterlord done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way to do it is to specify the size of the container, give it `overflow:auto` and set the `background-size` to `cover`:

```
height: 100vh; /* change this to whatever else fits your case*/
background-size: cover;
overflow: auto;
```

That's the basics, the rest is depending on your needs. Also note that if you use an element that is not displayed as block level by default, you probably want to add `display:block` or `display:inline-block;` to it and depending on case, set a `width` for it.

Here's a working example. Apart from the properties specified above, you don't need much from it (i.e: I added a fixed overlay to make sure the text reads, because it's a random image and it could be white and, most likely, you don't need it):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.fixed-bg {
  background: url("https://unsplash.it/1200/800") no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fixed-bg > *{
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect (except I ended up using `overflow-x: auto` and `overflow-y: hidden` as there was no need for a scrollbar in my specific case)! One question - what's the need for the `background-cover` style?

Comment: @carefulnow: positions and scales the background image to the smallest possible size that covers the entire area of the element, without distorting it. Depending on case, it either crops on vertical or horizontal direction. If the proportion of the element and background image match, no cropping is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
    background: url(images/example.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the css:

```
#topbar
{ 
   width:115%;
}
```

Comment: Why 115%? This highly depends on the device the webpage is viewed on.